# definition 1-form $df$

Tags: differential-forms

From Munkres:

[image]

Any idea why my book writes $f’(x;v)$? The derivative is a function from $A\to \mathbb R$ after all, so how can it suddenly have an argument of $(x;v)$? It looks like they're using some sort of chain rule, but I don't really see it. Any clarification on $f'(x;v)$ is appreciated.

Comment: The only derivative I know that "is a function from $A \to \mathbb{R}$" is a directional derivative, which needs both a point *and* a vector to produce a value.

Comment: I've not read Munkres, but since he also uses the expression $df(\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{v})$, it sort of looks like he is using $(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{v})$ to refer to a point of the tangent bundle $TA$; it would be one of the points lying in the fiber $T_\mathbf{x}A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative, *at a point $x$*, is a linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

This linear map depends, of course, on the point $x$. So it is common to see notations like $L_x$, or $f'_x$ etc.

Munkres seems to be putting that dependence in an argument, which is essentially just a stylistical choice (when talking about derivatives). Formally, he is considering the map
\begin{align*}
f': A \times \mathbb{R}^n &\to \mathbb{R} \\
(x,v) &\mapsto L_x\cdot v.
\end{align*}

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the fantastic explanation on notation! (which had really put me off track somehow)